# Unity (photon/network): how to instantiate object at same position your local player is at?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate 2d bullet under my player with this:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class Network_Shoot : Photon.MonoBehaviour {

    public void OnClick_Shoot()
    {
        if (photonView.isMine) 
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate (Path.Combine ("prefabs", "Network Bullet"), transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

In the inspector I've set `OnClick()`-event to the script in the player prefab that triggers this method. Method gets called but the bullet is always instantiated at position `0, 0, 0` with rotation `0, 0, 0`. If I do

```c#
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(transform.position);
}
```

I get the real position in my console. What is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

First, all network instantiated prefabs need to be in Resources folder. Second, the item needs to have Photon View attached, so you can synchronize it's position and rotation.

Comment: Path.Combine takes the prefab from the Resources/prefabs folder so that's handled. Player prefab (that has the Network_Shoot script attached to it) has PhotonView-component on it so that's handled aswell. I solved this by removing the OnClick()-event from Inspector and setting it dynamically on Start()-method. I don't know why it worked, so I can't set that as an answer, but it worked.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Path.Combine.html), `Path.Combine` doesn't take the prefab from Resources folder. The instantiated prefab should have `Photon View` attached.